Which 5-qubit QEC circuits can simulate magic state distillation?
Theoretically, any 5-qubit error correction code's decoding circuit should be able to implement magic state distillation, but I have tried many circuits for simulating magic state distillation, and most of them fail to achieve the goal. Are there any additional requirements for selecting the decoding circuit?
Details:
The magic state distillation protocol begins with copies of quantum states of the form,
$\rho_0=(1-\epsilon)\left|T_0\right>\left<T_0\right|+\epsilon\left|T_1\right>\left<T_1 \right|$
$\left|T_0\right>$ and $\left<T_1\right|$ are the eigenstates of the Clifford operator $T=SH$.
Such a state can be prepared from an arbitrary state $\rho$ by using a dephasing transformation based on the  gate $T$
$\Gamma(rho)=\frac{1}{3}(\rho+T\rho T^\dagger+T^\dagger\rho T)=(1-\epsilon)\left|T_0\right>\left<T_0\right|+\epsilon\left|T_1\right>\left<T_1 \right|$
The magic state distillation algorithm involves taking five copies of the noisy input magic states $\rho_0$ of the form shown above，and projecting this five-qubit state onto the codespace for the five-qubit error correcting code described by four stabilizers. Additionally, there is another Clifford operator $\sigma^y H$ that needs to be applied at the end. Its purpose is to transform $\left|T_0\right>$ into $\left|T_1\right>$.
Projecting the five copies of the noisy magic state onto the codespace for the five-qubit code can be done by applying the decoding algorithm for the five qubit code, followed by 4 $Z-basis$ measurements.
The Difficulty I Encountered
My simulation program consists of three parts: the first part is preparing the noisy magic state, the second part is the decoding circuit, and the third part is applying the additional Clifford operator $\sigma^y H$.
I have tried using multiple decoding circuits documented in the literature or online resources. However, only one specific decoding circuit produced simulation results that matched the theoretical values (as shown in Figure 1). The other circuits deviated from the theoretical values and failed to achieve the magic state distillation effect.
So are there any additional requirements for selecting the decoding circuit?
$Figure 1$ Catalyst/magic state distillation

$Figure 2$ One of the unsuccessful simulation circuits，I know this circuit already encompasses all three parts.

Simulation Result
Figure 3:The first decoding circuit used

Figure 4:The second decoding circuit used

A study of the robustness of magic state distillation against Clifford gate faults
Universal Quantum Computation with ideal Clifford gates and noisy ancillas

Welcome to the SE. Please elaborate on how you perform the simulation in detail, and what the output is for the two different encoding circuits. Putting your simulation code here will also greatly enhance the chance to solve your problem.

Thank you very much for your guidance！I don't think there are significant errors in my program itself, as the first decoding circuit has achieved the target result. Replacing it with the second decoding circuit is just a normative modification of the original program. I have already added simulation results above.
